# How to stop initialized integer being given a seemingly random specific value?

Tags: c, int

I have been working on this program for a day or so now and I haven't had any issues nor have I seen the particular problem before.

It was working before it just didn't work...below is the code that is causing problems.

When I declare my variables iflag, vflag, and nflag to be zero I got predictable functionality prior to starting work today. But now **iflag is somehow 4196496.**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 512

//Prototypes:
char *read_line(FILE *fpntr);
int grep_stream(FILE *fpntr, char *string, int iflag, int nflag, int vflag);

int line_number = 1;             // Line number in the file.
int width = 6;                   // Spacing

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    FILE *fpntr = NULL;              // Pointer
    char *PATTERN = argv[1];         // String we are attempting to match with our search.
    char *FILE_PATH = NULL;          // Optional file pathway.
    int eflag = 0;                   // Track errors
    int vflag, iflag, nflag = 0;     // Track param usage.

    printf("Inside the grep_stream \n");
    printf("iflag: %d\n", iflag);    // Outputs 4196496
    printf("nflag: %d\n", nflag);    // Outputs 0
    printf("vflag: %d\n\n", vflag);  // Outputs 0
...
}
```

I can include the rest of the code if that would help but essentially the moment I do my declaration it is set to that weird number so I don't think there can be anything funky elsewhere causing the issue.

Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: You never initialized `iflag` or `vflag`. The code `nflag = 0` only initializes `nflag`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop that from happening?

It's unfortunate, but no.  The onus is on you to initialize it.  There's no standard feature of C that you could capitalize on that would initialize it for you.

> When I declare my variables iflag, vflag, and nflag to be zero I got predictable functionality prior to starting work today. But now iflag is somehow 4196496.

This code:

```
int vflag, iflag, nflag = 0;     // Track param usage.
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
int vflag;
int iflag;
int nflag = 0;     // Track param usage.
```

It's critical to note that `iflag` and `vflag` are not initialized here.

---

## How can I avoid this problem in the future?

In my opinion, warnings and other static analysis methods are critical to productivity for C/C++.

```
$ clang -Wall -Wno-unused-variable uninit.c 
uninit.c:25:27: warning: variable 'iflag' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("iflag: %d\n", iflag);    // Outputs 4196496
                          ^~~~~
uninit.c:22:21: note: initialize the variable 'iflag' to silence this warning
    int vflag, iflag, nflag = 0;     // Track param usage.
                    ^
                     = 0
uninit.c:27:29: warning: variable 'vflag' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("vflag: %d\n\n", vflag);  // Outputs 0
                            ^~~~~
uninit.c:22:14: note: initialize the variable 'vflag' to silence this warning
    int vflag, iflag, nflag = 0;     // Track param usage.
             ^
              = 0
2 warnings generated.
```

Here is an example where the compiler can warn you about these errors before you waste time debugging.  Note that I censored the `unused-variable` warning but only because your example code omits some usage.  Normally, this can be a useful warning.

Comment: Right - I suppose I took it for granted initially. Is there any particular reason that this issue would not have come  up earlier? I am just now getting these problems after quite a bit  of time.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that this depends on something called "Undefined Behavior".  It generally means that the compiler's free to take what you might think of as shortcuts.  It results in programs whose execution may not be consistent.  Depending on the execution environment, some inputs to variable behavior might be: other stuff left on the stack or heap or which programs had run prior to this one.

Comment: Ok - that makes a lot more sense. I never considered it. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

In Java and some other languages, values are automatically initialized to represent the 'null' of their respective types, int = 0, double = 0.0, string = "" and so on.

This is not the case in C, tho. The memory that is allocated may contain some previous garbage values that the variable will contain at the start and it's up to you to initialize it correctly.